# Can I fetch() multiple times in a loader function and extract it with one useloaderdata()?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

ive been watching people use useLoaderData() to extract the values that been passed to the react component

Here's my code in App.js,

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path='/' element={<RootLayout/>}>
      
      <Route path='user' loader={userLoader} element={<User/>}></Route>
      
    </Route>
  )
)
```

In  element,

```
import { useLoaderData, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const User = () => {

    const users = useLoaderData();

    return (
        <div >
        </div>
    );


}

//loader function
export const userLoader = async () => {

    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/user');
    return res.json();
}

export default User;
```

My question is, isit possible to fetch from multiple URL and return once to the browser and extract with useLoaderData()?

which something looks like this

```
export const userLoader = async () => {
    const res1 = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/user');
    const user= res1.json();
    const res2 = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/car');
    const car= res2.json();

    return {user, car};    
}
```

i had tried above code and it returns a weird promise

and i noticed whenever i surround the json result with {} in loader function it returns a promise, why is it so?

```
//loader function
export const userLoader = async () => {

    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/user');
    return {res.json()}; ////why u cant put {}?
}

export default User;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The curly brackets only define a scope or object literal, it's the function being declared `async` that makes it *implicitly* return a Promise object. The `useLoaderData` hook and RRD Data router do the awaiting. When you use the following

```js
export const userLoader = async () => {
  const res1 = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/user');
  const user = res1.json();
  const res2 = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/car');
  const car = res2.json();

  return { user, car };    
}
```

The code is resolving the implicit return with an object with properties `user` and `car` that are themselves unresolved Promise objects, e.g. `res.json()` returns a Promise.

The loader should `await` the JSON Promises as well.

```js
export const userLoader = async () => {
  const res1 = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/user');
  const user = await res1.json();
  const res2 = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/car');
  const car = await res2.json();

  return { user, car };    
}
```

If none of these fetch requests are dependent on any other previous request resolving then you can speed things up a little bit by fetching things concurrently using `Promise.all`.

Example:

```js
export const userLoader = async () => {
  const [user, car] = await Promise.all([
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/user').then(res => res.json()),
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/car').then(res => res.json()),
  ]);

  return { user, car };    
}
```